# I got an error when comparing non-nullable type to null

Tags: c#, nullable

I've got problems at this line:

```
int? nextLevel = (from p in cd.Objective
                  where p.Parent_ObjectiveID == null
                  select p.ObjectiveID).Max() + 1;
```

The error specifies:

The null value cannot be assigned to a member with type System.Int32 which is a non-nullable value type.

How can I fix it?

UPDATE:

But p.Parent_ObjectiveID is int? datatype. It can be null.

Comment: Note that if your using this to determine new IDs as part of database access, you can't always garuntee that the next ID will be maxid+1. Concurrency issues aside, its possible that there was a number of failed inserts that have generated the auto-increment value with you being aware.

Comment: Just post an answer pointing to the solution that you found and accept it.

Answer (score 3):

The objectiveID is of type which is not nullable. So whats the point of checking it for NULL type? You never can assign a null value to a non nullable value. May be use objectiveID? instead..

Comment: But p.Parent_ObjectiveID is a nullable type. I mean: int?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, p.Parent_ObjectiveID cannot be `null`, (i.e. a "non-nullable" type). So there is no need to check if it is a `null` or not.

So to fix it, get rid of the `where` part, or change it from `null`, to an `System.Int32` value.